# using linq to flatten data

Tags: c#, linq

How can I flatten the following data using linq.

*Here I want to group by Column1 and Column2 and Column3 are the Key and value of a Dictionary*

```
Pete, small, 2.0
Pete, medium, 3.5
Sbux, small, 2.5
Sbux, medium, 3.0
Mcd, large, 3.0
Mcd, refill, 5.0
Dd, refill, 4.0
Dd, solo, 2.0
cb, xlarge, 4.0
cb, premium, 5.0
Sb, premium, 4.0
Sb, xlarge,refill,extra, 7.0
```

to following -

```
Pete, small, 2.0, medium, 3.5
Sbux, small, 2.5, medium, 3.0
Mcd, large, 3.0, refill, 5.0
Dd, refill, 4.0, solo, 2.0
Cb, xlarge, 4.0, premium, 4.0
Sb, premium, 4.0, xlarge,refill,extra, 7.0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `Column2` values do not repeat within `Column1` group, the solution can be as follows:

```
var flat = data
    .GroupBy(item => item.Column1)
    .Select(g => new {
        Column1 = g.Key
    ,   Dict = g.ToDictionary(r => r.Column2, r => r.Column3)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: This works! How would i search for a list of items in the flat list? for e.g if I lookup xlarge,refill it should return Sb

Comment: @user793468 There's no key `"xlarge,refill"` in any of `"Sb"`s two items. If you wanted to look for all items with `"xlarge,refill,extra"` key, you'd find it with `var keys = flat.Where(f => f.Dict.ContainsKey("xlarge,refill,extra")).Select(f => f.Column1).ToList();`

Comment: how should i transform the original data to make lookup possible for partial items in the key?

Comment: @user793468 This depends on how flexible you want your match to be. If you're OK with substring match, replace `f.Dict.ContainsKey("xlarge,refill,extra")` with `f.Dict.Keys.Any(k => .Contains("xlarge,refill"))`. This is not a hash look-up, so it would take linear time. It wouldn't find `"xlarge,extra"` blocks, either. To do that you would need to restructure your data to avoid multi-element keys.